# Laravel 5.2 post route returns plain html text

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, laravel-5

whenever I send a post request to 'tasks/add' i want the user to return to a new page, but all I get is plain html text in a popup.

Route.php code

```
Route::post('tasks/add', function() {
    return view('secrets');
});
```

this is my ajax request :

```
$("#frm").submit(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             var customer = $("input[name=customer]").val();
             var details = $("input[name=details]").val();
             var dataString = 'customer='+customer+'&details='+details;

             $.ajax({
                url: "tasks/add",
                type:"POST",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

                    if (token) {
                          return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                    }
                },
               data : dataString,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(dataString);
                    alert(data);
                },error:function(){ 
                    alert("error!!!!");
                }
            }); //end of ajax

            });

        });
```

Anybody has had this issue before?

Comment: Could you show what exactly data do you receive?

Comment: You are putting the response in an 'alert()' so the html just shows as html text. You don't want that, you want to redirect to a new page, not alert the result

Comment: It was just the html of the page i was trying to load.

@tam I removed the alert out of the ajax request, but now the post does nothing.

When i look at my post response, it's just a plain html file, but I want that html to load for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ajax to call your Route method. So when `Route::post(...)` returns the view `'secrets'`, it returns it to the Ajax method and becomes held by the `data` variable. Saying `return` in your Routes file doesn't magically mean redirect to a certain view, it is just like any other function that returns a value.

You currently have `alert(data)` which just says make an alert with whatever is held by `data` which in this case is the html text of your view.

Instead, take out the `alert()` and put

```
window.location.replace('<path/to/secrets>')
```

to redirect to the page you want upon success.

Assuming your Routes file has something like :

```
Route::get('/secrets', function() {
    return view('secrets');
});
```

You could say

```
window.location.replace('/secrets')
```

Comment: That's indeed a solution to make it work, but I would like to keep it clean and handle my redirects through laravel route.php. So basicly I would like my user to get redirected to the 'secrets' page after the post is done. Is this possible?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it returns again plain html to my ajax request. Anyway I thank you a lot for helping me out. I will keep my redirection through ajax :)

Comment: If I think of something else I'll let you know, but I think that is the way to do it. In general I find working with Ajax in Laravel can sometimes get a bit messy, just how it is.

Comment: I agree, If you have any better suggestions than using ajax for post/get request, you can always send me a message.